# python requests api not posting in-memory zipped file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, zip

*question*: How can I get this to work

I'm trying to use the python requests api to send a zipped file to a server. I saw this method in the docs:

```
r = requests.post(url, files=open('foo.png', 'rb'))
```

but the difference between what I'm doing, is that the zipped file that I have is in memory, there's just a python object, no physical zipped version of the file is created:

I'm using the zipfile api, and this is how I'm creating my zip file:

```
inMemoryOutputFile = StringIO()
outFile = zipfile.ZipFile(inMemoryOutputFile, "w",
        compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

and trying the following (after writing to the zip file):

```
r = requests.post(url, outFile)
```

however its not working, looks like the object is not being recognized as a parameter. here's the stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve/bin/cogs", line 11, in
<module>
    sys.exit(main())   File "/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cogs/run.py",
line 396, in main
    return run(sys.argv)   File "/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cogs/run.py",
line 384, in run
    return instance()   File "/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve//src/ctl.py",
line 53, in __call__
    handler = uploader(self.url, self.file)   File "/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve//src/uploader.py",
line 24, in __call__
    response = self.session.post(url, files=payload) 

#this is where I'm adding the file (the payload)

File "/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
line 511, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)   File
"/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
line 454, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)   File "/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
line 388, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),   File "/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py",
line 296, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)   File "/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py",
line 447, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)   File "/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/upload-script-ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py",
line 150, in _encode_files
    fdata = fp.read() TypeError: read() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

actual code:

```
inMemoryOutputFile = StringIO()

    parentDir, dirToZip = os.path.split(dirPath)
    def trimPath(path):
        archivePath = path.replace(parentDir, "", 1)
        if parentDir:
            archivePath = archivePath.replace(os.path.sep, "", 1)
        if not includeDirInZip:
            archivePath = archivePath.replace(dirToZip + os.path.sep, "", 1)
        return os.path.normcase(archivePath)

    outFile = zipfile.ZipFile(inMemoryOutputFile, "w",
        compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for (archiveDirPath, dirNames, fileNames) in os.walk(dirPath):
        for fileName in fileNames:
            filePath = os.path.join(archiveDirPath, fileName)
            outFile.write(filePath, trimPath(filePath))
        if not fileNames and not dirNames:
            zipInfo = zipfile.ZipInfo(trimPath(archiveDirPath) + "/")

            outFile.writestr(zipInfo, "")
    outFile.close()
    return outFile
```

Comment: Did you `inMemoryOutputFile.seek(0)` to rewind the file? Your three examples don't seem to have much to do with each other. You give us an abbreviated trace that stops where you call requests, not where the error is, and then a second stack trace for a completely different requests call. I can't make sense of it.

Comment: You are sending an empty file?

Comment: @tdelaney sorry, its 1 stack trace, i just added the comment in the middle to specify where I'm calling the post method.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no I'm writing to the zip file but its not relavant

Comment: @PadraicCunningham since requests reads from the current file pointer, it will certainly appear empty if one doesn't seek to the beginning again.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks I'll try `inMemoryOutputFile.seek(0)`

Comment: @tdelaney I've posted my code for zipping/writing to the in-memory zip file, where would I add `inMemoryOutputFile.seek(0)` ?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, before you add it to the zipfile, not sure that is going to fix your issue though as the error does not seem to come from that.

Comment: Your usage of `files=` is also wrong. The parameter takes a `dict` where the key is the name of the POST variable and the value should be the file handle http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `StringIO` buffer to `requests`, not the `ZipFile`. `ZipFile.read("somefile.txt")` reads an uncompressed file from the archive, it doesn't read the compressed binary stream. That `read` requires 1 parameter and that's why you got the strange error message. Rewind the file before posting or the `POST` data will be empty.

This example shows you the workflow.

```
import zipfile
from cStringIO import StringIO
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

buf = StringIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(buf, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zippy:
    zippy.write('somefile.txt')
buf.seek(0)

requests.post('http://localhost:8080', 
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'},
    data=buf)
```

Comment: It should be `files={'my_file': buf}`, not `data=` but otherwise correct. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: @JoshJ - That form is good for multipart messages, but using `data` for a single block of data is also correct. From the docs _"data – (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the Request."_

Comment: OP used `files=` so I was referring to what he used in his original example. I still upvoted you.